# Question on sum of normal variable

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a small doubt.

If X and Y are standard normal variables, is $ Z=(X+Y)/\sqrt { 2 } $
a standard normal variable ?

If I am correct, $X+Y$ follows $N(0, 2)$.
So, Z must follow $N(0, 2 / \sqrt { 2 } ) $

and not $N(0, 2)$.

Am I right ?

Comment: You are perfectly correct in doubting the assertion of the second sentence of your question. $Z= (X+Y)/\sqrt{2}$ is a standard normal random variable only if you _also_ assume that $X$ and $Y$ are **independent** standard normal random variables. As far as the next two sentences are concerned, note that $\operatorname{var}(aW) = a^2 \operatorname{var}(W)$ and so $X+Y \sim N(0,2)$ while $(X+Y)/\sqrt{2} \sim N(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are **independent** standard normal, then your calculation is correct: the random variable $\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}$ has variance $1$, and is normal.

Under the assumption of independence, $X+Y$ is indeed normal with variance $2$. Dividing $X+Y$ by $\sqrt{2}$ divides the variance by $(\sqrt{2})^2$, that is, by $2$, giving variance $1$.

Comment: Thanks to all and specifically to André who always has great answers.